# View Google analytics for firebase data in Google Analytics app

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Just curious if its possible, since Google analytics and Google analytics for firebase seems to be two different things. It would be convenient to see analytics for all my projects at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment, however you can see data collected by all the Firebase apps present in a project in a single dashboard.

Firebase data can flow into Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager but vice versa is not possible.